# What are the Eigenstates in a Flux Qubit?

Tags: quantum-information

By reading Wikipedia I get that the two Eigenstates of a Flux Qubit are clockwise or counter-clockwise circulating current. This is somehow intuitive, as my current-generated H-Field compensates the magnetic flux to integer values of the flux quantum.

However, reading other sources, the Potential of a Flux Qubit looks like this: [image: Double-Well Potential]

So I have two lowest states: a symmetric solution-wavefunction and an antisymmetric one. 
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left( \Phi_1 \pm \Phi_2\right)
$$
And by measuring, I should get one of these, right? But these solutions don't seem to correspond to the above idea of my current flowing clockwise or counter-clockwise, or do they?

What part of my derivation is wrong or where do I miss a link?

Comment: Who tells you the circulating currents *don't* correspond to these solutions?

Comment: I can definitely answer this in great detail. First, help me out: what are $\Phi_1$ and $\Phi_2$ in the question?

Comment: So from my understanding $Phi_i$ are the right or left circular flowing currents of one flux quantum...